# Support more characters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Whenever I try to use the following characters in Python 2.7 "šđžćč" the console gives some non-ascii character error.

This is fixed by adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the header.

However when I try to use the characters this happends. Eg.

The code is `print "Upiši svoj tekst:"` but `Upi┼íi svoj tekst:` is printed.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure your terminal/console is set up to handle the character set?

Comment: @AI G I'm not sure. I'm on Windows 7. Can you help me out with it? **EDIT:** Pretty sure it is set up. When I run echo čćžđš the terminal outputs čćžđš

Comment: @Jan: but then you are also *entering* characters into your terminal. That happens to encode those characters to the right codec. `chcp` will tell you what codepage was used there.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but does it make a difference when you say `print u"Upiši svoj tekst:"`? (note the `u` prefix)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Okay, it says 852 which, according to Microsoft means Slavic (Latin II) which does support all of the characters I need.

Comment: @Jan: so encode your Python text to that codec. Or just use Unicode throughout and leave it to Python to do so automatically when printing. UTF-8 is not the same codec as cp852. Take into account that cp852 *only* supports ASCII + Slavic characters, nothing else.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks! The u  works very well. But only on the print function. 
When I try 

text = raw_input u("Upiši svoj tekst: ")

I get invalid syntax.
Same thing for text = raw_input (u"Upiši svoj tekst: ")

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't need anything else than ASCII + Slavic characters. I referenced UTF-8 because I knew it supports the characters.